# Cannot find symbol '/' in class name

Tags: java, netbeans

When I compile my java class. There are some errors of cannot find symble '/' in class name. Below is a sample code from my class:

```
public TransactionSearchResponse submit(TxnSearchRequest req)
{
    url = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(req.getBaseUrl()))).append("/txns/search").toString();
    method = "POST";
    return (TransactionSearchResponse)sendRequest(req, com/COMPPONENT/api/TransactionSearchResponse);
}
```

**Be cause of copyright from author of this code block. sendRequest Method is deleted.**

Netbeans cannot recognize the dash '/' in the class name "com/COMPPONENT/api/TxnResp". And the class name contains some parts:

Package name: com.COMPONENT.api

Class name: TxnResp

Java file name: TxnResp.java

The dash '/' show in red color as Netbeans mask it an error line. The only hint I got from Netbeans are "Add import for com.COMPONENT.api.TxnResp" or "Flip Operands of '/' (may alter semantics), and I did that but got no luck. And when I try to run the code, it generate an error of "Cannot find symbol". Can you help me to solve this issue?

Regards,
Dung Tri

Comment: Don't use '/', use '.' (dot) to separate the components of a package name.

Comment: I have tried but it got an error at cannot find symbol at .api.

Comment: You may have to add .class, if the sendRequest has a second parameter of type java.lang.Class. - How is sendRequest declared?

Comment: To clarify the error message: slash ('/') is the symbol for the numeric operation *division*, so it can't be used at all the way you wrote it.

Comment: All classes just stay inside package com.COMPPONENT.api (it is a full name of a single package). There is only one mistake may happen here that I got wrong way to call the class TxnResp in this context.

Comment: You have to show me the declaration of method sendRequest.

Comment: I did show the method "sendRequest" on the question.

Comment: OK - it's just as I thought - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method sendRequest is declared like

```
Object sendRequest( Request x, Class<?> y )
```

you'll have to call it with an instance of a java.lang.Class object:

```
... = sendRequest( request, com.COMPPONENT.api.TxnResp.class );
```

Appending .class is the way of obtaining an instance of a certain Class object (not to be confused with an instance of TxnResp which is created using new TxnResp).

Also, given

```
com.COMPPONENT.api.TxnResp txnResp = new com.COMPPONENT.api.TxnResp();
```

the expression

```
txnResp.getClass()
```

results in an instance of the `Class<com.COMPPONENT.api.TxnResp>` but of course the .class notation is more convenient for your purpose.

Comment: Thank for your answer! Now I understand your answer more clearly.